# Junit test spring mvc

Tags: junit, spring-3

i want to log in using spring mvc security to test the proj, but an exception was raised while runing the junit test method

the test method:

```
 @Test
public void loginUser1Ok() throws Exception {
    HttpSession session = mockMvc
            .perform(
                    post("/j_spring_security_check").param("j_username",
                            "admin").param("j_password",
                                    "secret"))
            .andExpect(status().is(HttpStatus.FOUND.value()))
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/")).andReturn().getRequest()
            .getSession();

    Assert.assertNotNull(session);
```

}

this exception was raised

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response status expected:<302> but was:<200>
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$2.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:141)
at com.orange.weather.WebApplicationContextControllerTest.loginUser1Ok(WebApplicationContextControllerTest.java:157)
```

Answer (score 0):

A response with status code 200 is not a redirect. I expect that

```
HttpSession session = mockMvc
        .perform(
                post("/j_spring_security_check").param("j_username",
                        "admin").param("j_password",
                                "secret"))
        .andExpect(status().is(HttpStatus.FOUND.value()))
        .getSession();
```

will work.